# Azure URL Authorization Rules Using AAD Documentation

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

I'm trying to secure specific paths for certain AD groups using easy auth for a web directory on Azure's app service. Referencing the article below, I'm able to lock down specific paths by configuring the authorization.json file.

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/11/17/URL-Authorization-Rules.html

However, I'd like to take things a little further and lock down specific sections based on AD groups. The quote from the same 2016 article made it sound like this was possible:

*"We are also working on additional authorization policies that can be configured. As an example, in a coming update you can expect to see support for restricting access to specified URL routes to Azure AD Security Groups"*

The problem is that I haven't been able to find any documentation as to how to utilize this feature. Is there something I'm missing or did this option get scrapped?

Answer (score 0):

As of now I dont see any update on authentication at Azure AD group level. This seems to be, yet to done feature. Recently Azure App service authentication has been updated and comply with OAuth2 but this part is either untouched or yet to available to tryout.
You can request an update on this either over github page or https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps.

If you're a developer then you can check latest code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-app-service-authentication